Sum Values In Array Vbscript
In the below code, I was able to loop through 9 (amount of files will vary) txt files and grab a certain line within those text files. The value I grabbed is a quantity value and always listed in the same spot. I'm having some difficulty getting a sum of those quantities.
Current code:
Set oFile2 = FSO.OpenTextFile(File.path, ForReading)

i = 0
'process text files
Do While oFile2.AtEndOfStream <> true
text = oFile2.ReadLine
'WSCript.Echo text
    ReDim Preserve SSheet(i)
SSheet(i) = text
i=i+1
Loop

oFile2.Close
Set oFile2 = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing

'find row and strips down quantity
Dim QtyTrim
QtyTrim = Mid((SSheet(30)),6,4)

'convert quantity to int
Dim QtyInt
QtyInt = CInt(QtyTrim)

WSCript.echo QtyInt


Does this answer your question? How to sum values in a loop

Sum Up Numbers From Text Files

Calls a procedure (Main) that loops through the files of a given folder (FOLDER_PATH) and for each file with a given extension (FILE_EXTENSION), calls a function (GetQuantity) that retrieves a string (FoundString), defined by the function's constants, converts the string to an integer and passes the integer back to the procedure where it is added to a variable (Total). Finally, shows a message box with the resulting total.
Focus on the GetQuantity function and how it is utilized in the calling procedure which may be different than what you had in mind. Not sure why you decided that the preceding code is irrelevant.
Keep in mind that the function returns either an integer or Empty.

Option Explicit

Main

Sub Main()
    
    Const FOLDER_PATH = "C:\Test"
    Const FILE_EXTENSION = "txt"
    
    Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    If Not fso.FolderExists(FOLDER_PATH) Then
        MsgBox "The path """ & FOLDER_PATH & """ doesn't exist!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim fsoFile, Quantity, Total, FilesFound
    
    For Each fsoFile In fso.GetFolder(FOLDER_PATH).Files
        If StrComp(fso.GetExtensionName(fsoFile), FILE_EXTENSION, _
                vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            FilesFound = FilesFound + 1
            Quantity = GetQuantity(fso, fsoFile.Path)
            If Not IsEmpty(Quantity) Then
                Total = Total + Quantity
                Quantity = Empty ' reset for the next iteration
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    If IsEmpty(FilesFound) Then
        MsgBox "No ." & FILE_EXTENSION & "-files found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If IsEmpty(Total) Then
        MsgBox "No quantities found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Continue, e.g.:
    MsgBox "Total: " & Total, vbInformation
    
End Sub

Function GetQuantity(fso, FilePath)
    
    Const STRING_LINE = 31
    Const STRING_FIRST_CHAR = 6
    Const STRING_LENGTH = 4
    
    Dim fsoTextFile: Set fsoTextFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FilePath, 1)

    Dim Line, FoundString
    
    Do Until fsoTextFile.AtEndOfStream
        Line = Line + 1
        If Line = STRING_LINE Then
            FoundString = fsoTextFile.ReadLine
            Exit Do
        Else
            fsoTextFile.ReadLine
        End If
    Loop
    
    fsoTextFile.Close
    
    If IsEmpty(FoundString) Then Exit Function
        
    On Error Resume Next
        GetQuantity = CLng(Mid(FoundString, STRING_FIRST_CHAR, STRING_LENGTH))
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function


This worked much better than my previous example, very much appreciated!
